# Implement queue for stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010

I have a basic SELECT stored procedure in SQL Server and this is connected to an MS Access front end. Users are receiving table locks when multiple users try to run the same stored procedure (i.e. ODBC--call failed or Table is currently locked). Is there a way to implement a queue or prevent this from happening.

I have tried moving servers to closer to see if it was a latency issue and tried OPTION (MAXDOP 1) in case it was a processor issue.

```
(@username as varchar(20),
@searchcriteria as varchar(50)
)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON; 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

--SET @username = 'caddo';
--SET @searchcriteria = 9;
--SET @portfolio = 'WH – Apollo';
--PRINT '%'+ RIGHT(CAST(@situsloanid as varchar(10)),@loanLength) + '%'

SELECT tblPortfolio.PortfolioID, 
tblAssets.AssetID, 
tblAssets.ModelEntity, 
tblPortfolio.Portfolio, 
tblAssets.SitusLoanID, 
tblEmployees.Last AS AMIntials, 
tblEmployees_1.Last AS TeamLead, 
tblStatus.StatusType, tblEmployees.NetworkUserName, tblRegion.ID, tblRegion.Region, 
IIf(1=1 Or 0=1,1,IIf(@username=[tblEmployees].[NetworkUserName] Or @username=[tblEmployees_1].[NetworkUserName] Or @username=[tblEmployees_2].[NetworkUserName] Or @username=[tblEmployees_3].[NetworkUserName] Or @username=[tblEmployees_4].[NetworkUserName] Or @username=[tblEmployees_5].[NetworkUserName],1,0)) AS [Select], 
tblEmployees_1.NetworkUserName, tblEmployees_2.Last AS PMLead, tblEmployees_3.Last AS Analyst, tblEmployees_4.Last AS Admin, tblEmployees_5.Last AS ComplianceLead, tblAssets.AssetName, 
tblAssets.BorrowerName, tblEmployees.compliance AS ComplianceBool, tblAssets.SitusLoanID, tblAssets.Alias 

FROM tblAssets LEFT JOIN tblEmployees AS tblEmployees_5 ON tblAssets.ComplianceID = tblEmployees_5.LoginID 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployees AS tblEmployees_3 ON tblAssets.AnalystID = tblEmployees_3.LoginID 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployees AS tblEmployees_2 ON tblAssets.PMLeaderID = tblEmployees_2.LoginID 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployees AS tblEmployees_1 ON tblAssets.AMLeaderID = tblEmployees_1.LoginID 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployees ON tblAssets.AssetMngrID = tblEmployees.LoginID 
LEFT JOIN tblStatus ON  tblAssets.PipelineStatusID = tblStatus.StatusID 
LEFT JOIN tblEmployees AS tblEmployees_4 ON tblAssets.ServicerContactID = tblEmployees_4.LoginID 
LEFT JOIN tblPortfolio ON tblAssets.PortfolioID = tblPortfolio.PortfolioID 
LEFT JOIN tblRegion ON tblAssets.RegionId = tblRegion.ID 

WHERE (1=1 )
AND (tblPortfolio.Portfolio Like '%'+ @searchcriteria + '%' 
OR tblAssets.SitusLoanID Like '%'+ @searchcriteria + '%' 
OR tblAssets.BorrowerName Like '%'+ @searchcriteria + '%' 
OR tblEmployees_2.Last Like '%'+ @searchcriteria + '%' 
OR tblAssets.AssetName Like '%'+ @searchcriteria + '%'
OR tblAssets.Alias Like '%'+ @searchcriteria + '%'

AND (IIf(1=1 Or 0=1,1,IIf(@username=[tblEmployees].[NetworkUserName] 
Or @username=[tblEmployees_1].[NetworkUserName] 
Or @username=[tblEmployees_2].[NetworkUserName] 
Or @username=[tblEmployees_3].[NetworkUserName] 
Or @username=[tblEmployees_4].[NetworkUserName] 
Or @username=[tblEmployees_5].[NetworkUserName],1,0)))=1)

ORDER BY tblAssets.AssetName, tblAssets.SitusLoanID

OPTION (MAXDOP 1);
```

I would like the users to be able to run the SP and mot receive lock errors or for them to be placed in a que to receive the expected data.

Comment: You might have more luck at [dba.se]. I don't see anything that causes exclusive locks here, no writes happen. You could just add `WITH(NOLOCK)` but that doesn't gain insight into the true issue and can cause unexpected results when writes are happening to tables you're querying.

Comment: Your WHERE clause is effectively scanning the tables, is my guess. Also, hard to recommend options without knowing what indexes exist on what tables.